# import csv file in Python py

Tags: python, csv, utf-8

I want to import my csv file in google colab.

```
import pandas as pd

a = “/content/drive/MyDrive/ordner/Mappe 2 (1).xlsx”
b = pd.read_csv(a, engine=“python”, encoding=“utf-8”)
b.head()
```

But it gives me this error:

UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xa6 in position 10: invalid start byte

I tried with engine=, encoding=, or “//“ but it always doesn’t work. I don’t know, what the problem is or did I write something wrong in my excel file?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tUP7A.png)

Can somebody help me please?

Comment: A .xlsx file is NOT a CSV file.  Can you use something other than `read_csv`?

Comment: do you know how to convert a .xlsx file to a CSV file?

Comment: You use "Save As" from Excel.

Comment: Try the `pd.read_excel` function, also `python` does not appear to be a valid engine type from the docs, I don't think you need to set that.

Answer (score 2):

You are using `read_csv` but you have an `xlsx` file. Use the following instead:

```
import pandas as pd

# Specify the path to the Excel file
excel_file = '/content/drive/MyDrive/ordner/Mappe 2 (1).xlsx'

# Read the Excel file into a pandas DataFrame
df = pd.read_excel(excel_file)

# Display the DataFrame
print(df)

df.head()
```

Comment: I try now this code

Answer (score 0):

Try to use read_excel with engine:

`variable_name = pd.read_excel(r'filename.xlsx', engine='openpyxl')`

You could try another approach, like converting your 'filename.xlsx' to 'filename.csv' using spreadsheets. I hope this helps.

Comment: The problem is already solved but thanks for your help

Comment: Now I now two options how to solve it